# How to restrict Sandbox LMA License to match Production License Status/Count?

Tags: isv, lma, trial

How to restrict Sandbox LMA License to match Production License Status/Count?

If your AppExchange package includes a free trial, in Production the app installs well with TRIAL as the status. However, it appears as free in sandbox orgs.

Is there a way to have Sandbox org installation follow the same licensing model that is configured to your package. When "a free trial" is offered, sandbox should get a trial license of x days instead of not active (does not expire).

For apps which can be used in Sandbox and serve the purpose, I need a mechanism to make the app behave as Trial for x days in Sandbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Free orgs get a free site-wide license to the package as well. There's no way to restrict this feature. It's designed to be used for trial/evaluation purposes.

Comment: My question is, particularly around Sandboxes?

Comment: @ChiragMehta That's correct, all packages get free licenses in Sandbox orgs.

Comment: yep, so coming back to my question is there a way to stop that and force similar policy as production for sandboxes too? maybe using some apex code which updates sandbox licenses record with expiry date whenever relevant prod license record is updated ??

Comment: @ChiragMehta No, there's no way to control this behavior.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by running apex logic in the form of batch program.